# Why is Messages acting extremely slow like Internet Explorer?

Tags: macos, iphone, messages

I've got my iPhone sync my messages to OS X. However, even though my Mac and my iPhone are connected to my perfectly stable home network, OS X is getting messages with a few minutes of delay. All the messages are immediately available on my iPhone while OS X gets them with a huge delay, making it impossible for me to chat with someone on my Mac using Messages. This is happening occasionaly, and is happening for both regular SMS and iMessage.

I'm on latest release versions of iOS and OS X, and I've got a perfectly fine Internet connection. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What happens if you wait for a message to come through on the Mac, then respond from there, leaving the app open & frontmost. Does it speed up subsequent messages? If the system thinks you're at your Mac, they should arrive there first. If it thinks you're on your phone, that's where they arrive first.

Comment: @Tetsujin Messages is almost always open on OS X and mostly frontmost when this happens.